# Autofac InstancePerRequest returns new isntance

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have an ASP.NET Web API, .Net 4.6.1 project where I need to capture some info in the middleware and then retrieve it in a code that will be called from controller. In .Net core it is very easy with registering my custom context class as Scoped and resolving it in different stages of message processing. In .Net Framework, what looked similar to it was Autofac's `InstancePerRequest` so I tried but it does not work as I expected. Apparently every time I do `BeginScope()` it returns a new instance even if I am within same reuest? I am implementing the `IAutofacContinuationActionFilter` interface where I resolve my service, registered with `InstancePerRequest`, then later in controller I try to resolve it again and get new instance. What am I missing here?

Oh and in the controller below, both instances of IHomeService: injected via constructor and resolved manually are creating new instances.

UPDATE:
The code above is oversimplification of the real situation. The call where I need the information passed from filter is in a separate class and call happens through a series of autogenerated code. The constructor injection is not an option for me so I was hoping to have a solution similar to .Net Core DI.

my WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        var container = MyContainerBuilder.Build(config);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

my container builder class:

```
public class MyContainerBuilder
{
    public static IContainer Build(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        builder
            .Register(c => new MyCustomFilter())
            .AsWebApiActionFilterForAllControllers()
            .InstancePerRequest();
        // var assembly = typeof(IHomeService).Assembly;
        // builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();
        builder
            .RegisterType<HomeService>()
            .As<IHomeService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

filter:

```
public class MyCustomFilter : IAutofacContinuationActionFilter
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteActionFilterAsync(
        HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> next)
    {
        using (var scope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope())
        {
            var hs = scope.Resolve<IHomeService>();
            ++hs.Counter;
            var hs1 = scope.Resolve<IHomeService>();
            ++hs1.Counter;
            var r = next().Result;
            return await Task.FromResult(r);
        }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
[Route("home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    public IHomeService HomeService { get; set; }

    public HomeController(IHomeService homeService)
    {
        HomeService = homeService;
    }
 
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public string Index()
    {
        var dr = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver as AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver;
        using (var scope = dr.GetRequestLifetimeScope())
        // This does not work either, returns new instance:
        // using (var scope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope())
        {
            var hs = scope.Resolve<IHomeService>();
            ++hs.Counter;
        }
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

service class I try to resolve:

```
public interface IHomeService
{
    int Counter { get; set; }
}
public class HomeService : IHomeService
{
    public HomeService()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Yet another instance of HomeService!!!");
    }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you use constructor injection instead of creating scopes manually?      using (var scope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.BeginScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope()).  I am not sure what this row does, but it seems like it creates a new scope instead of using the scope of the http request (why is there a beginscope?)

Answer (score 2):

You can't create your own request scope, you need to get it from the request message. In the filter, that's like:

```cs
var scope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();
```

An example filter showing this is [in the Autofac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filter-attributes-are-singletons)

However, since you're using Autofac interfaces, they're injected by Autofac for each request - if your filter needs a per-request service, it's better to make it a constructor parameter on the filter. You only need to do service location if you're *not* using Autofac filter interfaces.

If you seriously need service location in the filter, you can still use the constructor to make things easier - add an `ILifetimeScope` parameter to the filter constructor and you'll get the request scope as a parameter.

For the controller, same thing: inject what you need in the constructor rather than using service location. If you need the request scope because you can't escape service location, either inject an `ILifetimeScope` into the controller constructor or get the request lifetime off the `HttpRequestMessage`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Unfortunately that is not an option for me due to constrains enforced by existing code. In real code this is happening not in controller but in separate class that is called from controller. The call happens through series of autogenerated code so there is no way of modifying that either and I can't do constructor injection. The only option was manual resolution, but as far as I understand that is simply not possible with Autofac?

Comment: "Manual resolution" is service location. I gave a couple options for that. However, the long and short is - to get the request scope you need the request message. That's a Web API thing and basic architecture in there, not an Autofac-specific restriction. You can't create your own request scope, you have to get the one provided. I think my answer solves the question as presented; if it doesn't, then you changed things up too much in your question and it's not an accurate representation of what you're actually doing. If so, you probably need to ask a new question.

Comment: I agree, in my attempt to simplify things I went too far )) I just updated the question with new info, though I get a feeling it is simply not possible with the Autofac

Comment: If you fundamentally change the question it's a new question. And, again, the challenge you're seeing is NOT Autofac specific, this is how Web API works. Ask a new question and include an example showing the use of the auto-generated code. Note that use in the sample. Show the actual auto-generated code if you can. In the meantime, if this answer solved the question as originally posed, please accept it.